# Simple loop with shortcode rendering problem

Tags: theme-development, loop

The following loop is in a `single.php` template file. It works ok, but the shortcodes aren't rendered.
**the loop:**

```
<div id="circula-destaque">
      <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
      <?php ik_mostra(the_content()); ?>        
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

**outputs:**
Some text I put **html works fine**, but `[shortcodes]` aren't rendering, any sugestions?

edit: that `ik_mostra()` function is here:

```
function ik_mostra($secao) {
    if ($secao != NULL) :
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $secao);
    endif;
}
```

A way I tried to render it.

Comment: What does `ik_mostra()` function do? `the_content()` function doesn't return anything, so using it as another function param is a little bit strange, I guess.

Comment: oh, i'm sorry about that. editted

Comment: OK, so as I've already said, `the_content` function does not return anything and it already should apply `the_content` filter, so you don't have to use your function at all (`$secao` will be null every time ;) ). Correct this part, check if it's working and then we will debug it further.

Comment: You don't have to use `apply_filters( 'the_content'` on `the_content( )`. This is done by default inside `the_content( )`.

Comment: oh, I forgot to tell that i did try without apply_filter, that was an attempt... =/

Comment: what shortcodes? are you using plugins for any other shortcodes than the generic Wordpress ones?

Comment: Something is very weird. Disable you plugins. Does that help?

Comment: That function doesn't make any sense, just remove the call to it, and stick with calling just `the_content()` in your **single.php** .. i can't see what that `ik_mostra` function aims to do.